# Как вернуть большую структуру будет дешевле?

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Допустим, некий код извлекает из указателя структуру. Структура имеет размер больше чем указатель/ссылка, будет ли дешевле обернуть эту структуру в класс, и вернуть ссылку на этот класс, и из него извлекать структуру, нежели возвращать эту структуру?

P.S. Такой вопрос появился, т.к. вспомнился один термин из документации, что если тип имеет размер больше чем размер ссылки/указателя, то его лучше возвращать/передавать по ссылке/указателю.

Одна из структур:

```
#region Usings

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

#endregion

namespace libvlc.net
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct Event
    {
        internal readonly EventType Type;
        internal readonly IntPtr Caller;
        internal readonly EventData Data;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal readonly struct EventData
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaEvents Media;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerEvents MediaPlayer;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaListEvents MediaList;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaListPlayerEvents MediaListPlayer;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly VlmMediaEvent Vlm;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        internal readonly struct MediaEvents
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaMetaChanged MetaChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaSubItemAdded SubItemAdded;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaDurationChanged DurationChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaParsedChanged ParsedChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaFreed Freed;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaStateChanged StateChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaSubItemTreeAdded SubItemTreeAdded;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        internal readonly struct MediaPlayerEvents
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerBuffering Buffering;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerPositionChanged PositionChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerTimeChanged TimeChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerTitleChanged TitleChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerSeekableChanged SeekableChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerPausableChanged PausableChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerScrambledChanged ScrambledChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerVideoOutput VideoOutput;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerLengthChanged LengthChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerSnapshotTaken SnapshotTaken;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerMediaChanged MediaChanged;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaPlayerAudioVolume AudioVolume;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        internal readonly struct MediaListPlayerEvents
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaListPlayerNextItemSet NextItemSet;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        internal readonly struct MediaListEvents
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaListItemAdded ItemAdded;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaListWilAddItem WillAddItem;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaListItemDeleted ItemDeleted;
            [FieldOffset(0)] internal readonly MediaListWillDeleteItem WillDeleteItem;
        }
    }

    #region Media

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaMetaChanged
    {
        internal readonly MetaType MetaType;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaSubItemAdded
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr NewChild;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaDurationChanged
    {
        internal readonly long NewDuration;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaParsedChanged
    {
        internal readonly int NewStatus;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaFreed
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr MediaPtr;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaStateChanged
    {
        internal readonly State NewState;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaSubItemTreeAdded
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr NewItem;
    }

    #endregion

    #region MediaPlayer

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerBuffering
    {
        internal readonly float NewCache;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerPositionChanged
    {
        internal readonly float NewPosition;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerTimeChanged
    {
        internal readonly long NewTime;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerTitleChanged
    {
        internal readonly int NewTitle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerSeekableChanged
    {
        internal readonly int NewSeekable;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerPausableChanged
    {
        internal readonly int NewPausable;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerScrambledChanged
    {
        internal readonly int NewScrambled;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerVideoOutput
    {
        internal readonly int NewCount;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerLengthChanged
    {
        internal readonly long NewLength;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerSnapshotTaken
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr FileName;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerMediaChanged
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr NewMedia;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaPlayerAudioVolume
    {
        internal readonly float Volume;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Media List

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaListItemAdded
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr Item;
        internal readonly int Index;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaListWilAddItem
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr Item;
        internal readonly int Index;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaListItemDeleted
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr Item;
        internal readonly int Index;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaListWillDeleteItem
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr Item;
        internal readonly int Index;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Media List Player

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct MediaListPlayerNextItemSet
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr Item;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Vlm

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal readonly struct VlmMediaEvent
    {
        internal readonly IntPtr MediaName;
        internal readonly IntPtr InstanceName;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Если структура <= 16 байт, то процессор может скопировать структуру за парочку инструкций. Если становится больше, то он использует цикл для копирования. Имхо стоит опираться на 16 байт.

Если структура не боксится и живет всегда на стеке - то дешевле будет структуру завести (до 16 байт), чем создавать класс и нагружать им GC.

Comment: Размер структуры 32 байта. А что насчет указания параметра как тип структуры с ключевым словом `in`, вместо передачи указателя?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/write-safe-efficient-code
тут как раз в пунктах описываются юзкейсы. in поможет в данном случае - не будут создаваться защитные копии, можно так же посмотреть на readonly ref struct и ref readonly return (для больших структур)